# Is it possible to cout without overwriting current text in the input?

Tags: c++, cout, cin

Okay, so let's say I have a program that couts a line while the user may be typing in information.

For this example, let's say we're using the code

```
cout << "THIS CODE IS BEING COUTED" << endl;
```

Let's say for our example, the user is in the process of typing up an input and as it stands they have only entered "hello", but has not yet pressed enter.

As it stands, when the line is executed, the user will see
"helloTHIS CODE IS BEING COUTED"
and they will be given a new line to input information.

What I want to do is instead of cout'ing, I would like to get the text in the current input, erase it from the input, cout the line that needs to be cout'ed, and then re-enter the info into the input.

Does this make sense or is this a bunch of jumbled nonsense?

Thanks for reading.

Edit: Clarification: I want it so if I have a string entered into my input and I cout, that the cout will be displayed above my input instead of inserting it past my input. I also want my input to be unaffected so the user can continue typing or delete what was already entered.

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about `cout` being "verbed"!

Comment: I'm wondering if you are concerned about debugging info interferring with your input.  If so you can use cerr and redirect it, or use a debug logfile

Comment: Why you wants to output information while user is inputting something,   the cout is in another thread?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the input character by character then when you need to output your text you could move the output position to the start of the line by printing carriage return, '\r'. Then your output will overwrite the current input, after which print a line feed and reprint what has been input so far

```
cout << "\r" << output << "\n" << currentinput;
```

If the output is shorter than the input then you will only partially overwrite the input, in which case you could pad the output with spaces up to the length of the current input

Answer (score 0):

You may ask user in one, main thread with `cin >> data` there and read data from stdin in other thread by `fread` or something like that what works with `FILE*` handle.

After the data you want was typed by user you may clear screen (for example by `clrscr()` in `conio.h` or by any other better way) and cout what you want.